# Ansible: given a list of ints in a variable, define a second list in which each element is incremented

Tags: python, functional-programming, ansible, jinja2

Let's assume that we have an Ansible variable that is a `list_of_ints`.

I want to define an `incremented_list`, whose elements are obtained incrementing by a fixed amount the elements of the first list.

For example, if this is the first variable:

```
---
# file: somerole/vars/main.yml

list_of_ints:
  - 1
  - 7
  - 8
```

assuming an increment of 100, the desired second list would have this content:

```
incremented_list:
  - 101
  - 107
  - 108
```

I was thinking of something on the lines of:

```
incremented_list: "{{ list_of_ints | map('add', 100) | list }}"
```

Sadly, Ansible has [custom filters for logarithms or powers](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#math), but not for basic arithmetic, so I can easily calculate the log10 of those numbers, but not increment them.

Any ideas, apart from a pull request on https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.1.1.0-1/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/mathstuff.py ?

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    incremented_list: []
    list_of_ints:
      - 1
      - 7
      - 8
    incr: 100

 tasks:
   - set_fact:
       incremented_list: "{{ incremented_list + [ item + incr ]  }}"
     no_log: False
     with_items: "{{ list_of_ints }}"

   - name: show cntr
     debug: var=incremented_list
```

Comment: Hi @rob-h, this actually worked, thanks!
What I was really trying to achieve, though, was doing dis declaratively, without using a task for this.

This is not actually possible with Ansible 2.1, I am trying to submit [PR #17251](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/17251) to see if this can be useful.

In the meantime, a friend suggested this solution, which makes use of just one task instead of two:

Comment: Solution with single task, using default() filter:


`incremented_list: "{{ ( incremented_list | default([]) ) + [ item + incr ]  }}"`